# Extract extension from email address in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to extract the extension from email address.

**Input:** test@work.com
**Output:** com

**Input:** test@work.test.com
**Output:** test.com

I tried,

```
(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE('test@work.test.com'), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('test@work.test.com')) - 1)))
```

This works only the first input. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to *remove* any characters prior to and including the first period (`.`) after the at symbol (`@`). I would use `CHARINDEX` and `STUFF` for this:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(V.Email,1,CHARINDEX('.',V.Email,CHARINDEX('@',V.Email)),'')
FROM (VALUES('test@work.com'),
            ('test@work.test.com'))V(Email);
```